# Executing appium test on kobiton device

Tags: automated-testing, c#, appium, mobile-automation

I'm running some of my Appium test cases which are written in c# under .net platform on a real time device which is attached to my workstation.
Below is my code and it works fine.

```
  public void AppiumSetupMethod()
        {

            string appPath = @"G:\Projects\UGL\DTZMobility\Mobility.client\release\android\dev-2.1_.apk";
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "");
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Android");
           capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "4.1.0");
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, "true");

            capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "CB5A1THVTT");

            capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.XXX.XXX.XXX");

            capabilities.SetCapability("Version", "4.1.0");
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebview", "true");
            capabilities.SetCapability("sessionOverride", "true");
            capabilities.SetCapability("app", appPath);
            capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.XX.XX");

            capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "0");
            capabilities.SetCapability("recreateChromeDriverSessions", "true");


            driver = new AndroidDriver <IWebElement> (new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
        }
```

But how should i run the same test on a kobiton device.
According to  kobiton's documentation i have did some initial setup, as below,
But i don't know how to add the `kobitonServerUrl`.

```
public void kobitonSetupMethod()
    {
        String kobitonServerUrl = "https://chathudagr8:2d9c748a-b5c9-4714-8372-a7fe9393b10d@api.kobiton.com/wd/hub";
        string appPath = @"G:\Projects\UGL\DTZMobility\Mobility.client\release\android\dev-2.1_.apk";

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("sessionName", "Automation test session");
        capabilities.SetCapability("sessionDescription", "");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
        capabilities.SetCapability("captureScreenshots", true);
        // The maximum size of application is 500MB
        // By default, HTTP requests from testing library are expired
        // in 2 minutes while the app copying and installation may
        // take up-to 30 minutes. Therefore, you need to extend the HTTP
        // request timeout duration in your testing library so that
        // it doesn't interrupt while the device is being initialized.
        capabilities.SetCapability("app",appPath);
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceGroup", "KOBITON");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy On Nxt");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");




        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.IsJavaScriptEnabled, "true");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.XX.XX.XXX");
        capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebview", "true");
        capabilities.SetCapability("sessionOverride", "true");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.XXX.XXX");
        //capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.dtz");
        capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "0");
        capabilities.SetCapability("recreateChromeDriverSessions", "true");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `kobitonServerUrl` the with `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub` solved the problem.

Comment: Is your problem gets resolved with this?

Comment: Yes. But now there is another issue. Im investigating on it.

Comment: Please credit Bharat's answer if it was correct